# Web Platform Installer error installing VS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I just got a new W7 laptop, and am trying to install VSExpress/Sql Server Express etc using the Web PI 4.5.

However, when doing so, it continually fails with the message:

> Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web (Default Locale) This product did
>   not install successfully: Downloaded file failed signature
>   verification and may have been tampered with

I downloaded Web PI from Microsoft's website.  Am I missing something?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Not sure if exactly the same but it kept telling me that the file it downloaded did not pass signature verification.

So I went here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30669 and downloaded small installer (900+ kb) and ran it.

Worked like a charm.